# PHP : multiple inputs into other multiple inputs

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays

I using jquery to add / remove inputs

i use append to add multiple Tr for Date / revenue

also i use another append to add multiple td for revenue in same Tr of date

i Add multiple date inputs and into this table i add multiple revenue inputs

I have to use name="date[]" to can use for loop and insert each one in mysql table

but in sametime there is multiple name="revenue[]"

Here is example

```
    <form method="post" action ="">
    <table>
<tr>
<td>Date : <input type="text" name="date[]" value="25/07/2013"></td>

<td>Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[]" value="1"><br>
    Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[]" value="2" ><br>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Date : <input type="text" name="date[]" value="26/07/2013"> </td>

    <td>
    Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[]" value="12"><br>
    Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[]" value="13"><br>
    Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[]" value="14"><br>
    </td>
 </tr>   

    <tr>
    <td>Date : <input type="text" name="date[]" value="27/07/2013"></td>
    <td>
    Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[]" value="30"><br>
  </td>
 </tr>  
 </table>
    <br><br><input name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">

    </form>
```

PHP code

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$date = $_POST['date'];
echo "Results<br>";
for($i = 0; $i<count($date); $i++){
echo "Date : $date[$i] <br>";
print_r($_POST['revenue']);
echo "<br><br>";
}
}
?>
```

Results is :

```
Date : 25/07/2013
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 12 [3] => 13 [4] => 14 [5] => 30 )

Date : 26/07/2013
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 12 [3] => 13 [4] => 14 [5] => 30 )

Date : 27/07/2013
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 12 [3] => 13 [4] => 14 [5] => 30 )
```

I wanted results to be like that

```
Date : 25/07/2013
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2)

Date : 26/07/2013
Array ( [0] => 12 [1] => 13 [1] => 14)

Date : 27/07/2013
Array ( [0] => 30 )
```

i want to insert each date into a table with the multiple revenue in same row

Like In Row

```
Date : 25/07/2013     Revenue : 1-2
Date : 26/07/2013     Revenue : 12-13,14
Date : 27/07/2013     Revenue : 30
```

Its very important for me, Thank You Very Much

Comment: Your loops are wrong, but the main problem is, that there is no way to tell which "revenues" belong to what "dates".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're creating your `date` and `revenue` inputs, name them with the array notation, but include indexes:

```
<tr>
    <td>Date : <input type="text" name="date[0]" value="25/07/2013"></td>
    <td>
        Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[0][]" value="1"><br>
        Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[0][]" value="2" ><br>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>Date : <input type="text" name="date[1]" value="26/07/2013"> </td>

    <td>
        Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[1][]" value="12"><br>
        Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[1][]" value="13"><br>
        Revenue : <input type="text" name="revenue[1][]" value="14"><br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You should then be able to read them from `$_POST` as `$_POST['date'][0]` and `$_POST['revenue'][0][0]`, `` `$_POST['revenue'][0][1] ``, etc.

Comment: but as i said i using jquery to add / remove multiple inputs for date / revenue , so i think if i used your way, when i coding php , it will cause a problem if $_POST missed

Comment: No - you can create these elements in jQuery, with these names. I've just posted the HTML here to show how it works.

Comment: this is the way to do it, i do it all the time. although i do name="update[0][date]", name="update[0][revenue][0]", name="update[0][revenue][1]", etc

Comment: Yes Mike W, i understood you, but look, i will do the following with jquery i will use append : rename revenue input to : revenue[1][] in first Tr of date, then i added with jquery second TR of date and renamed : revenue input to revenue[2][] , what about if i deleted second TR of data which has revenue[2][] , and i will use for loop on date array, so how i can check the revenues of this date ?

Comment: Your PHP script can iterate over the dates in one `foreach` loop, and iterate over the reveues in a second, inner, `foreach` loop. Exactly how you do that depends on your application. It's really a different question. Have a go at it, and post a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: ok thank you very much, your answers was helpful ,i will try your way which rename revenues to revenue[1][]  / revenue[2][] , i will use for loop for dates and foreach loop for revenues,